# Attributes Error in loop

Tags: python, tweepy

I use Tweepy to collect twitter user informations. I basically want to print some fields using a loop for, avoiding

Here is my code :

```
fields = ["id", "screen_name", "ceated_at"]  # We create a list of 3 fields
user = api.get_user("twitter")               # We collect all available informations of the user called 'twitter'
for f in fields :                            # For our 3 fields, we want the associate information
    print f + " : " + user.f
```

I obtain :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test v1.2.py", line 16, in <module>
      print f + " : " + user.f
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'f'
```

The expected result :

```
id : 783214
screen_name : twitter
created_at : 2007-02-20 14:35:54
```

Why 'user.f' doesn't work (last line) whereas 'user.id', 'user.screen_name' and 'user.created_at' work well outside the loop ?

I'm sure this is an evidence for all of you but, for a beginner like me, it's a complete mystery ! :)

Thanks a lot in advance for your explainations,

Comment: Use `getattr`: `getattr(user, f)`

Comment: Thanks a lot (and sorry for the duplicate question, I really didn't know where I had to start looking for) :)